# What would a git hook look like that checks the correct version of python was used?

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks, pre-commit-hook

I've been trying to find an example of a git hook that checks if the files being committed are python, and if they are what version of python was used.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hook like [`sebdah/git-pylint-commit-hook`](https://github.com/sebdah/git-pylint-commit-hook), modifying it to exit if pylint reports an error (which it will for non-python files)

But for detecting the writing style, there are no magic bullet: as stated here, you would need to [compile with python2 or python3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38624782/6309) (still in the hook).